# iPhone simultaneous sound output

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to play up to 40 different sounds at the same time. I currently instantiate an `AVAudioPlayer` for every one of these and it almost works. The main problem is a lag for the next sounds after many sounds have been played at the same time. However, it is crucial for the next sounds not to be delayed by this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use CoreAudio framework for more low-level control.
Like here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html